# When changing set_max_velocity_scaling_factor(0.5), moveit couldn't plan trajectory

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am right now working to slow down the velocity of the abb_irb6640 model. When I use `set_max_velocity_scaling_factor(1)`, everything works fine. But when I want to use `set_max_velocity_scaling_factor(0.5)`, I get an error :
`Invalid Trajectory: start point deviates from current robot state more than 0.01 joint 'joint_1': expected: 0.575495, current: 0.6802`.

My system is: melodic and ubuntu 18.04

Any leads will be very helpful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400683/when-changing-set_max_velocity_scaling_factor(0.5),-moveit-couldn%27t-plan-trajectory/) by [Dhara](https://answers.ros.org/users/102753/dhara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2022-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found an answer:

Because I used `group.execute(wait=False)`, moveIt does not wait for the trajectory to complete the first path, as it does not track the status of trajectory execution. And as soon as moveit received second `execute` command, it sends this above error. `set_max_velocity_factor()` was not an issue. So, used this `wait` parameter cautiously.

---

Originally posted by [Dhara](https://answers.ros.org/users/102753/dhara/) with karma: 16 on 2022-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure exactly why the change would cause an issue, but you could try one of the following:

- in your moveit_config package for your robot, in `launch/trajectory_execution.launch.xml` there is a line `<param name="trajectory_execution/allowed_start_tolerance" value="0.01"/>` that you can change to be more tolerant. (Note, this may not help everything, but could be a place to start looking).
- Before you execute the trajectory, do you set your `move_group` start state? (i.e. `move_group.setStartStateToCurrentState()`?

I do know i've had issues with the UR models for the first bullet point, not much experience with abb, however. But those might be some places to start.

---

Originally posted by [emielke](https://answers.ros.org/users/27456/emielke/) with karma: 261 on 2022-05-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dhara](https://answers.ros.org/users/102753/dhara/) on 2022-05-17**:
Hii,

I tried the first solution and set the tolerance to 0.05, but error stays the same. And I couldn't afford more tolerance in my process.
My planning sequence is something like this:

```
`abb.set_start_state(robot.get_current_state())
 abb.set_pose_target(table1, end_effector_link)
 plan = abb.plan()
 if plan.joint_trajectory.points:
    abb.set_max_velocity_scaling_factor(0.5)
    abb.execute(plan,wait=False)
    rospy.sleep(2)`
```

Is there any other solution?

**Comment by [emielke](https://answers.ros.org/users/27456/emielke/) on 2022-05-17**:
So like I said, I'm not familiar with abb, but what does the initial pose look like? Per [here](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/move_group_python_interface/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.html) you might need to send a joint move to get it away from an initial singularity, and then plan to a pose. But based on the fact you do it with velocity at 100% makes me think this isn't the case.

Is the velocity scaling the only thing changed?

**Comment by [Dhara](https://answers.ros.org/users/102753/dhara/) on 2022-05-17**:
yes, you are right. Only thing that is changed here is velocity scaling. I also test this code:
`abb.set_start_state_to_current_state() start_pose1.pose.position.z = start_pose1.pose.position.z + 0.6 abb.set_pose_target(start_pose1, end_effector_link) plan = abb_plan_path(abb) if not plan == False: abb.set_max_velocity_scaling_factor(0.2) abb.execute(plan,wait=False) rospy.sleep(2)`

But error stays the same. But when I use `abb.go()` for combine planning and execution ,everything works. Why is it like that?